# Extremely low attraction

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty

I have made a question I need to have answered before continuing in a OSDev tutorial. Here it is:
[Cannot link linker.ld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912909/cannot-link-linker-ld)

It has currently 32 views, 0 comments (2 favorites and 2 upvotes, no downvotes) that relate to the question/question problem (I wrote a comment saying thanks for the bounty, but that doesn't count here), and there is currently a +100 bounty given by a user by the name of Star OS. However, there are no answers and I have explained very well my environment and problem, and the tools that I am using.

The question is getting absolutely no attention. Can someone draw yet more attention (somehow, since I've tried all of the Stack Overflow's recommended/normal techniques to increase the amount of attention on that question)?

Comment: It is indeed a very unattractive question.  You are not doing a very good job of the "everybody loves my question and SO sucks" claim.   Don't use both accounts at the same time.  And if you put "I love kittens" in your profile then don't pick "Kitty" as the other account name.

Comment: Question is 2 days old. Bounty is recent. Patience. As your bounty (i assume starOS is another one of your accounts... doesnt change much though) ages, you'll get more views. Although looking in your answer. This was not a good question for stack. Like... At all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you imagine what would happen if *every* user wanting to attract more attention to his/her question would open a thread on Meta?

Just wait until the bounty expires; there's no regular way to attract more attention within the Stack Exchange network. You can try posting the link to the question on other websites (there's even a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) for that). Have you tried the [OSDev forum](http://forum.osdev.org) itself?

Comment: Forgot about the forum there. Though, i'm asking this beacuse of the extremely low information SO is giving me though the best efforts me and people have given me.